# Using cloudflare with vanity nameserver

Tags: dns, hosting, cpanel, cname, cloudflare

I'm trying to use a vanity nameserver with cloudflare on my domain. So far i managed to setup my vanity NS to NS1.site.com and NS1.site.com. I also activated cloudflare from the cpanel but i don't think its working correctly because when i preform a whois on the domain I'm getting my server ip address which means its not being redirected to cloudflare servers.

I also tried to add the domain manually through cloudflare website but i was asked to change my NS to their own. this way i will lose my vanity NS.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

i was thinking to forward the request from my vanity NS to cloudflare NS and then maybe cloudflare will work. can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps a silly question, but did you go to your registrar and change the name servers to point to cloudflare?

Comment: yes. i know how to point the NS to cloudflare. What i want to do is to use my vanity NS (made through dnsmadeeasy.com) with cloudflare but w/o the need to change my NS to cloudflare NS.

Answer (score 0):

"I also tried to add the domain manually through cloudflare website but i was asked to change my NS to their own. this way i will lose my vanity NS."

Then you need to activate through the hosting partner's panel option & not sign up directly. We don't manage the DNS when you activate through a partner's panel option, so your vanity nameservers would still work through your provider.